# withTransaction for Quartz Jobs in Grails?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

When I set a Grails [Quartz](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) job like this:

```
class TestJob {

    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: 5000l // execute job once in 5 seconds
    }

def execute() {

   def users = User.getAll()
   users.each { user -> 
     user.enabled = true
     user.save()

  }

 }

}
```

**Do I have to wrap the content of execute in a withTransaction block?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you need the transaction.

Actually, the Quartz plugin creates a persistence context, but doesn't create a transaction.